# Testing EventMachine with cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, eventmachine

I'm trying to write a cucumber feature and rspec tests for my application for accessing the twitter streaming api with twitter-stream. I've got the following code:

```
Then /^I should see the latest (\d+) tweets from my timeline$/ do |num|
  timeline = Starling::Timeline::Mine.new(@store)

  EventMachine::run {
    tweets = timeline.latest
    timeline.stop
  }

  tweets.length.should == num.to_i
end
```

the code for the method is:

```
def latest
  token = @token.get_token

  @stream = Twitter::JSONStream.connect(options)

  items = []
  @stream.each_item do |item|
    items << item
  end

  items
end
```

But, predictably, it stalls on the timeline.latest call. How can I properly test the logic inside my `latest` method?

Comment: What do you mean stalls? It's requesting data from the twitter server? Something else?